# I need to convert audio file from μ-law to PCM

Tags: java, audio, javasound, pcm, jmf

I need to convert wav file from **FORMAT 1** to **FORMAT 2**

**Format 1 :**
μ-law, 8000Hz, 64 kbps, mono

**FORMAT 2 :**
Container   WAV
Encoding    PCM
Rate    16K
Sample Format   16 bit
Channels    Mono

**Following is the Code snippet :**

```
File file = new File("audio_before_conversion.wav");
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true , true);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream1 = new AudioInputStream(
     new FileInputStream(file), audioFormat, numFrames);
AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream1, Type.WAVE, 
     new File("audio_after_conversion.wav"));
```

**Issue :**
But, this is not working. It playing some noise and also reducing my audio file length.

Edit 1: mu-Law to μ-law

Comment: is your input format μ-law ?   I have not heard of Mu-Laq

Comment: @scott Yes, μ-law.

Comment: http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/ may get you there.

Answer (score 2):

**Following code worked for me --**

```
File sourceFile = new File("<Source_Path>.wav");

        File targetFile = new File("<Destination_Path>.wav");

        AudioInputStream sourceAudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sourceFile);


        AudioInputStream targetAudioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, sourceAudioInputStream);
        System.out.println("Sample Rate1 "+targetAudioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameRate());
    AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Encoding("PCM_SIGNED"), 16000, 16, 1, 2, 8000, false);



        AudioInputStream targetAudioInputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, targetAudioInputStream);
        System.out.println("Sample Rate "+targetAudioInputStream1.getFormat().getFrameRate());

        try {
            AudioSystem.write(targetAudioInputStream1, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, targetFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `AudioSystem` and split up format conversion and audio writing into two different steps:

```
final File file = new File("audio_before_conversion.wav");
// open the audio stream
final AudioInputStream pcmStream8k = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
// specify target format
final AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true , true);
// this converts your audio stream
final AudioInputStream pcmStream16k = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, pcmStream8k);
// this writes the audio stream
AudioSystem.write(pcmStream16k, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("audio_after_conversion.wav"));
```