# Convert 8kHz mulaw to 16KHz PCM in real time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, twilio, audio-streaming, audio-converter

In my POC I'm receiving a conversation streaming from Twilio in 8kHz mulaw and I want to transcribe it using Amazon Transcribe that needs to get the audio in 16KHz and PCM.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954593/i-need-to-convert-audio-file-from-%CE%BC-law-to-pcm) how to convert a file but failed to do this in streaming... The code for a file is:

```
File sourceFile = new File("<Source_Path>.wav");
File targetFile = new File("<Destination_Path>.wav");
AudioInputStream sourceAudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sourceFile);

AudioInputStream targetAudioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, sourceAudioInputStream);
System.out.println("Sample Rate1 "+targetAudioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameRate());
AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Encoding("PCM_SIGNED"), 16000, 16, 1, 2, 8000, false);

AudioInputStream targetAudioInputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, targetAudioInputStream);
System.out.println("Sample Rate "+targetAudioInputStream1.getFormat().getFrameRate());

try {
    AudioSystem.write(targetAudioInputStream1, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, targetFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Actually Twilio gives me a playload in Base64 (8KHz, mulaw) but I have to convert it to 16KHz, PCM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a G.711 Decoder and Audio Resampler.

Steps to be followed :

1. use base64 decoder to decode the Payload received.
2. use this payload buffer and decode using the G.711 decoder (mulaw to pcm)
3. output of the G.711 decoder need to be given to the resampler for upsampling ( 8->16 KHz)

Finally all the buffers are ready in PCM 16KHz.

Comment: I hope your will be able to figure out the respective java libs.

Comment: Thanks! Will check soon

Comment: @mail2subhajit I am using nodejs https://github.com/rochars/alawmulaw to get PCM 16 . However, the outbound that I get is int16array. Do you know how do I pass it to Amazon Transcribe further?

Comment: @Sunil, Let me know what are the Amazon Transcribe interface ( API) you are using.?